# Customize EdgeNGramFilter minGramSize and maxGramSize in Hibernate Search 6.1.8 Final with Lucene backend

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I am trying to implement autocomplete inspired by the Search analyzer section in this [Hibernate Search 6.0.0.Beta2 release](https://in.relation.to/2019/10/28/hibernate-search-6-0-0-Beta2/)

This is the example from the above link that I am trying to follow.

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @FullTextField(
            name = "title_autocomplete",
            analyzer = "autocomplete",
            searchAnalyzer = "autocomplete_query"
    )
    private String title;

    // ... getters and setters ...
}
```

To define an analyzer named "autocomplete" and a search analyzer named "autocomplete_query", I followed the [10.6.4 Custom analyzers and normalizers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-analysis) and defined the the following custom lucene analysis configurer and create a new persistence.xml.

```java
public class CustomLuceneAnalysisConfigurer implements LuceneAnalysisConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
        context.analyzer("autocomplete").custom()
            .tokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
            .charFilter(HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
            .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
            .param("language", "English")
            .tokenFilter( ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)
            .tokenFilter(EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class);

        context.analyzer("autocomplete_query").custom()
            .tokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
            .charFilter(HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
            .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
            .param("language", "English")
            .tokenFilter(ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class);
    }
}
```

```xml
<property name="hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer"
  value="class:net.ad.mc.lucene_search.CustomLuceneAnalysisConfigurer"/>
```

My question is : is there a way to set the minGramSize and maxGramSize using the above method? I've gone through the official documentation but found no information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done similarly to how you have the `language` parameter specified for lower case filter.
`tokenFilter()` returns a DSL step exposing a parameter method through which you can pass any filter-related parameters:

```
public class CustomLuceneAnalysisConfigurer implements LuceneAnalysisConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
        context.analyzer("autocomplete").custom()
            .tokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
            .charFilter(HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
            .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
                    .param("language", "English")
            .tokenFilter( ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)
            .tokenFilter( EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class )
                    .param( "minGramSize", "3" )
                    .param( "maxGramSize", "7" );

        context.analyzer("autocomplete_query").custom()
            .tokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
            .charFilter(HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
            .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
                   .param("language", "English")
            .tokenFilter(ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class);
    }
}
```

In case you are unsure about parameter name strings - open a filter class implementation and look for a constructor accepting a map - it will have the parameter names in it.

Comment: See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-analysis-analyzers, in particular there's a link to the Lucene javadoc: https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_1/core/ and the Solr wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters. That's about the only documentation there is for Lucene analyzers.